# Выделить память для массива внутри функции

Tags: c++, строки, функции, динамические-массивы, выделение-памяти

Наверное, странный вопрос. Суть моей проблемы и моя задача вот в чем:
одна из функций моей программы(find_and_count) получает текст(массив строк) и подстроку, каждое вхождение которой в текст должна найти и зафиксировать(на какой строке и каком по порядку символе оно произошло). Количество вхождений заранее, естественно, неизвестно - оно будет найдено только в процессе работы функции.
Изначально память под массив id выделялась и освобождалась непосредственно внутри функции, и все работало, но теперь у меня появилась необходимость передавать ссылку на данный массив в find_and_count, чтобы в ней он создавался и заполнялся, уже после того как отработает эта функция - передавать его в другую(save_find_and_count), и только потом освобождать память.
Я не уверен, что так вообще делать можно (практически уверен в обратном), но я пытался:

```
int **id = nullptr;
find_and_count(text, rows, substring, length, count, id);
if (want_to_save())
    save_find_and_count(text, rows, substring, id, count);
for (int i = 0; i < tab_rows; i++)
    delete[] id[i];
delete[] id;
```

Конечно, работать это чудо отказалось. Получил ошибку "Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения.
id было 0x1110112." на строчке "delete[] id[i];".
Вот и интересно мне стало: это просто я что-то неправильно сделал, но в принципе такое провернуть возможно, или мне следует поискать другие пути решения проблемы? Если нельзя освобождать память, выделенную внутри других функций - быть может, у кого-нибудь будут идеи о том, что мне делать с этой прелестью?

UPD: Прототип функции find_and_count:

```
 void find_and_count(string *text, int rows, string &substring, int length, int &count, int **id);
```

Я пытался создать ссылку на массив "снаружи", передать ее в функцию, там выделить необходимое количество памяти и заполнить массив, после чего использовать его вне функции вновь. Код залить уже не смогу - успел обойти эту проблему другим, пускай и не самым красивым, не связанным с массивом id способом. И все же для общего развития и на будущее интересно знать, как писать подобное.
В комментариях сказали, что такими вещами заниматься - вполне легально, поэтому я буду очень рад, если кто-то поделится рабочим вариантом решения сей задачи: чтобы можно было выделить память для массива внутри функции, а, к примеру, как-то его обработать, вывести на экран и освободить память - уже вне ее.

Comment: Чтобы было понятно, что у Вас там происходит, пожалуйста, приведите прототип функции  `find_and_count(text, rows, substring, length, count, id)`. И правильно ли я понял, что память для `id` Вы выделяете именно в ней? Подозреваю, что Вы неверно описали ситуацию и массив `id` передаете туда не по ссылке, а как есть.

Comment: Без кода это все - разговоры в пользу бедных... Конечно, можно, надо просто делать это правильно. А как это делаете вы - без кода непонятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все аргументы функций в Си и С++ передаются по *значению*. Это означает, что при вызове функции значение из Вашей переменной передается (копируется) в параметр функции, который, по сути, является локальной переменной вызываемой функции. Как бы Вы не изменяли значение этой переменной - это все останется только внутри функции и никак не повлияет на ту переменную, которую Вы подставляли при вызове функции, и при завершении функции будет потеряно. Таким образом, когда Вы передаете в функцию `int **id`, Вы просто передаете текущее значение этого параметра, т.е. `nullptr` локальной переменной функции. Дальше Вы выделяете память внутри, присваиваете адрес этой локальной переменной и... при выходе из функции вся эта информация об адресе с выделенным куском памяти просто теряется. Получаете утечку памяти, а переменная снаружи функции так и осталась со своим значением `nullptr`. И при попытке работы с этой переменной в вызывающей функции Вы справедливо получаете исключение.

Чтобы изменить внутри вызываемой функции переменную из вызывающей функции, Вы должны передать адрес этой переменной. По сути ничего не изменится - этот адрес по тем же правилам передачи параметров будет скопирован в локальную переменную внутри вызываемой функции. Но теперь Вы можете внутри вызываемой функции использовать операцию разыменования указателя (*) для доступа к данным, которые хранятся по переданному адресу. Этот адрес уже будет иметь смысл в вызывающей функции, поэтому изменённое значение ячейки памяти будет доступно и там. Таким образом, чтобы создать "двумерный" массив внутри вызываемой функции и как-то "передать" его наружу через параметр функции, Вам нужно было в параметрах функции объявить это как `int ***id` и при вызове передавать адрес переменной id: `&id`. Такой способ будет работать и в Си, и в С++.

Но в С++, кроме этого, еще можно использовать механизм ссылок, который также передает в функцию адрес, но делает это "скрытно" от Вас: кроме заголовка функции нигде не будет видно, что передается именно адрес переменной: ни при вызове, ни внутри функции.
В этом случае, Вам следовало объявить этот параметр как-то наподобие: `int ** &id`.

Чтобы было проще понять, что происходит, можно было задать свой тип через `typedef`, например так: `typedef int**  array2d;` и объявить Вашу переменную для массива, соответственно, как `array2d  m;`; ну и так далее...

Для демонстрации всего этого привожу пример работы с таким "двумерным" массивом.
В одной функции я выделяю память, в другой - присваиваю элементам массива какие-то значения, в третьей - вывожу на экран. Объявление переменной для этого массива и освобождение памяти происходит в main(). В примере есть оба варианта: и через указатель, и через ссылку.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    void alloc_array_1(int rows, int cols, int ***a);
    void alloc_array_2(int rows, int cols, int ** &a );
    void initm(int rows, int cols, int **a);
    void printm(int rows, int cols, int **a);

    int **m = nullptr;
    
    int rows = 3, cols = 4;
    alloc_array_1(rows, cols, &m); // вариинт 1: через указатель на "массив": работает в С и C++
/// alloc_array_2(rows, cols, m);  // вариант 2: через ссылку на "массив": работает только в C++
    initm(rows, cols, m);
    printm(rows, cols, m);
    
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        delete[] m[i];
    delete[] m;
    
    return 0;
}


void alloc_array_1(int rows, int cols, int ***a)
{
    *a = new int*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        (*a)[i] = new int[cols];
}

void alloc_array_2(int rows, int cols, int ** &a )
{
    a = new int*[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        a[i] = new int[cols];
}

void printm(int rows, int cols,  int **a)
{
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < cols; j++)
            std::cout << a[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void initm(int rows, int cols, int **a)
{
    for(int i=0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j=0; j < cols; j++)
            a[i][j] = 10*(i+1)+j+1;
    }
}
```